# Writing about GIS methods on the example of QGIS

Tags: qgis, gis-principle, research

I am preparing a thesis that relies heavily on GIS, specifically using the QGIS platform to calculate area extents and similar types of data.

I have only recently learned how to use GIS technology so I am not sure how to write about the data processing and analysis I have performed in QGIS in the methods section of my thesis.

Are there any existing norms or protocols on how to write about GIS methods used in research?

Answer (score 3):

I would reference the methods section in some of the published literature related to your thesis to get a sense of the level of detail you will need to include. Flowcharts can be a good way to describe complicated geospatial workflows. If you use code for your geospatial analysis, provide very good GitHub Documentation — this way you can provide a reference to the GitHub repository and a more general description of your geospatial workflow in the methods.

The ultimate objective is to include enough methodology so that other researchers can reproduce your work by only reading your publication.